# How to specify sharing link type via csom?

Tags: development, permissions, csom, pnp, sharing

It's pretty easy to share document:

```
string link = context.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Documents/sample.docx",ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);

SharingResult result = context.Web.ShareDocument("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Documents/sample.docx", "someone@example.com", ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View,true, "Doc shared programmatically");
```

But unfortunately it's not enough for me. I need to specify shared link type. But I have no idea hot i supposed to do this in code behind. However it's pretty easy to achieve by UI [image: UI] or by ps([see for details](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39365.sharepoint-online-sharing-settings-with-csom.aspx)):

```
$ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $password)
$ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$spoTenant= New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($Ctx) 
$ctx.Load($spoTenant)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$spoTenant.DefaultSharingLinkType= [Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.SharingLinkType]::$SharingLinkType
$ctx.Load($spoTenant)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Moreover I've tried this code:

```
Office365Tenant tenant = new Office365Tenant(context.Web.Context);
tenant.LoadAndExecute();
tenant.DefaultSharingLinkType = SharingLinkType.Internal;
tenant.LoadAndExecute();

SharingResult result = context.Web.ShareDocument("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Documents/sample.docx", "someone@example.com", ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View,true, "Doc shared programmatically");
```

But no success.

UPDATE.
Another one way which I've found recently is using [microsoft graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink)
Just one thing you have to do is specify scope for new link:

```
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink
Content-type: application/json

{
  "type": "view",
  "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

Is there any alternatives in `csom` ?

Comment: So, you want the CSOM C# equivalent to the PS script ?

Comment: now I would like to emphasize that I can't specify scope for shared link in csom. However it's possible by microsoft graph.

Comment: sorry, do you want to create and share any anonymous link for a document ?

Comment: No I need to create a link to all people on organization. I mean scope of this link must be - organization. But using pnp core it's only possible to create an anonymous link or call ShareDocument which takes only one email.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand it much :( , how would you go about doing that via the UI ? Which section of the link you posted should i check ?

Comment: I've updated by posting an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native CSOM's `CreateOrganizationSharingLink` method to get the URL of the document.

You need to specify the full URL of the document in the parameter.

If you want the `edit` link, keep the 3rd parameter value set to `true`, else change it to `false` if you want the `view` link.

The sample code is as below:

```
var orgEditLink = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web.CreateOrganizationSharingLink(context, 
"https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Documents/abcd.docx", true);

context.ExecuteQuery();

var editUrl = orgEditLink.Value;
```

Reference - [CreateOrganizationSharingLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.createorganizationsharinglink.aspx)

Comment: btw, do you know what exactly method `ShareDocument()` does ? I mean `CreateOrganizationSharingLink()/CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument()` it's quite clear, because it returns created link's url. But `ShareDocument()` doesn't return any shared link's url. Can you clarify difference between `ShareDocument()` and `CreateOrganizationSharingLink/CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument()` please.